# Carousel stopped working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get why, but suddenly my Bootstrap Carousel stopped working. I want it starts onload.

Error from Chrome Console:

```
          Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'carousel' :3000/assets/application.js?body=1:18
          (anonymous function) :3000/assets/application.js?body=1:18
         jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery-1.7.2.js:1076
        jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery-1.7.2.js:1194
        jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.7.2.js:436
        DOMContentLoaded jquery-1.7.2.js:950
```

In my application.js:

```
        $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 2000
       })
```

In my layout:

```
       <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.7.2', 'jquery.validate.min','application' %>
```

Where is problem ?

Comment: Are you loading bootstrap-carousel.js?

Comment: all bootstrap files are in my js directory. modals and dropdowns are working.

Comment: Create a clone of your site [html/js/css] in http://jsfiddle.net, then start debugging from there, also show us the fiddle URL once created so we can collaborate in the debugging process.

Comment: Perhaps the carousel js file hasn't yet loaded? If you're not doing it already, try loading your js files before the actual call to it inside the html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure:

- Only one jQuery is include only once.
- bootstrap-carousel.js or bootstrap.js in included (not both and after jQuery).
- look at comment here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11233713/1416911 (same problem as yours)