# Bootstrap Carousel Not Automatically Sliding

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap by Twitter's carousel (latest version) and I've got it working - except that it doesn't begin to automatically slide. It works well after you've clicked one of the navigation buttons . Not sure why it's doing this.

Here's my JS setup in the header:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo tz_JS . '/bootstrap/jquery.js'; ?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo tz_JS . '/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js'; ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo tz_JS . '/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js'; ?>"></script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="active item">
    <div class="image-position-right">
        <a href="#"><img src="validimagelink.jpg" width="920" height="550" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="item">
    <div class="image-position-right">
        <a href="#"><img src="validimagelink.jpg" width="920" height="550" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
```

Also just added this to no avail:

```
<script>
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 1200
});
</script>
```

After making the above change, the javascript console says:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'carousel' 
(anonymous function) 
b.extend.ready jquery.min.js:29
u

Any thoughts on why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: Have you used $('.carousel').carousel() anywhere ?

Comment: Just updated with that script - but adding it has not helped

Comment: @WilliamH Make sure you add that javascript (`$('.carousel').carousel();`) in a `$.document.ready()` call.  If the div doesn't exist when `.carousel()` is called, it won't autorotate.

Comment: That did not help. Thanks though. I placed it before and then after the div was called.

Comment: @WilliamH Are there any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: I updated with the console error

Comment: Make sure that your JS files are loaded correctly and (just a shot in the dark), try including transition before you include carousel source library.

Comment: Sorry - I think it's a JS issue, but it's not because of the order - I've tried every arrangment

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 1200
    })
  });
</script>
```

If it still is not working, look for potential errors in the browser's (firebug/chrome..) console.

---

For

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'carousel' (anonymous function) b.extend.ready jquery.min.js:29 u
```

Make sure:

Only one jQuery is included

Only one bootstrap-carousel.js or bootstrap.js is included.

jQuery is included first, then bootstrap-carousel.js or bootstrap.js, then $(document).ready( ...

Comment: Thanks - but I made sure to follow it exactly and now have the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'carousel' 
jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery.js:1032
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery.js:1150
jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:421
DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Can you trigger the carousel on the .carousel class instead of #myCarousel

Comment: Finally solved it! My site was using a widget was was calling JS 1.4.... URG! But you're suggestions definitely helped troubleshoot - thanks!

Comment: If you're having this issue with Blazor see this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56547992/151325

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes using the wrong version of JQuery can effect the actions of the Twitters Boostrap carousel. They are currently running v1.7.1, if your using different it may be causing the errors.

If your not running v1.7.1 you can download it from here:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Also make sure that your code is wrapped in a document ready :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      // code here
  });
```

Comment: Thanks - but neither of those solutions suggestions worked. I replaced my current jquery with the 1.7.1 link and used the document ready snippet as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had your same problem and found the solution; As we both put the javascripts at the end of the page, the calling of the function must be put after them:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({ interval: 3000, cycle: true });
});
```

Sometimes you need to put the JavaScript file after the carousal. Actually before the end of the page.

Ref: http://twitterbootstrap.org/twitter-bootstrap-3-carousel-not-automatically-starting/

Happy coding. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function() 
 {       
     $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
     setInterval(function() { 
       $('#slideshow > div:first')
       .fadeOut(750)
       .next()
       .fadeIn(1000)
       .end()
       .appendTo('#slideshow');
                            },  11000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `NgRoute` and the above solutions didn't work for you, be sure to include the following javascript code on the very top of the template `NgRoute` injects into the `<ng-view></ng-view>`:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $('#Carousel').carousel({ interval: 2500 }) });
```

Also ensure that jQuery is included first before bootstrap.js is included. This helped me when I had this problem on my project.