# Bootstrap 4 Carousel not working in Blazor (preview 7) server side

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4, blazor-server-side

I followed the solution for using Carousel with Blazor, but get Object exception when I run the app.

[How to use Bootstrap Carousel in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513221/how-to-use-bootstrap-carousel-in-blazor)

_Host.cshtml:

```
<body>
    <app>@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>())</app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    @*<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>*@

    <script>
        window.initializeCarousel = () => {
            $('#mycarousel').carousel({ interval: 2000 });

            //see step 2 to understand these news id's:
            $('#mycarousel-prev').click(
                () => $('#mycarousel').carousel('prev'));
            $('#mycarousel-next').click(
                () => $('#mycarousel').carousel('next'));

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Razor Page:

@page "/fullDetails/{id:int}"
@using BlazorApp2.Data
@using System.Collections.Generic
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime;
@inject VehicleService VService
@inherits UIAttributes


<h1>Vehicle Details</h1>
<hr />
<div>
    @if (vehicleInfo == null)
    {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    @foreach (var img in images)
                    {
                        if (img.SeqNo == "1")
                        {
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="/images/@img.ImageName" alt="None">
                            </div>

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="/images/@img.ImageName" alt="None">
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" id="mycarousel-prev" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" id="mycarousel-next" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>



</div>

@*If using @code per new speck you get errors when using this type of format  await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("initializeCarousel"); -- where <object> while be seen as markup 08/06/2019*@

@functions{

    VehicleFullDetails vehicleInfo;
    VehicleImage[] images;
    string first { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    int id { get; set; }


    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        vehicleInfo = await VService.OnGetVehicleFullDetailsAsync(id);
        images = vehicleInfo.Images.ToArray();
    }

    private  IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;


    bool firstRender = true;

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync()
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {

 (line 107)           await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("initializeCarousel");
            firstRender = false;
        }
    }



}
```

[2019-08-07T15:51:05.848Z] Error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at BlazorApp2.Pages.FullDetails.OnAfterRenderAsync() in C:\projects\blazor\gettingStarted\BlazorApp2\BlazorApp2\Pages\FullDetails.razor:line 107
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't work with Blazor in a way it worked with default Razor pages earlier, Because Server-side Blazor uses WebAssembly and transfers data to user in binary format.

And when `<script>` transferred in parts it can't run.

**There is two way of solving your problem:**

1) - one is change Blazor from Server side to Client Side (so user downloads full page with all scripts)

2) - second is to use **JavaScript interop** how to use it you can read in official MS documentation [ASP.NET Core Blazor JavaScript interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

You also have some syntax errors, in your code:

`await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("initializeCarousel");`

But you referring to JS script so it should be js file like this:

`await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("initializeCarousel.js");`

Comment: Thanks, but this is a server-side exercise. If I read the documentation correctly, client-side uses web assembly script.

Comment: _"Server side Blazor uses WebAssembly"_ is fundamentally wrong. _Blazor Webassembly_ (also known as Client Side Blazor) uses web assembly. Server side blazor uses a small java script on the client side. - Worth a downvote

Answer (score 0):

I placed the script into a initCarousel.js file and added it to _host.cshtml page. I then modified my @function code to:

```
 bool firstRender = true;

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync()
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {

            await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("initializeCarousel");
            firstRender = false;
        }
    }
```

The server-side application now cycles through the images and allow next/prev selection.

Thanks to Chris Sainty for the clarification: https://chrissainty.com/using-javascript-interop-in-razor-components-and-blazor/