# Is this possible to integrate jQuery UI components inside Blazor application?

Tags: jquery-ui, client-side, blazor

I want to integrate the jQuery UI component within the Blazor client-side application. The Spinner component looks better in jQuery UI. is this possible? how to integrate it?

I expect to integrate this Spinner component into my Blazor client-side application?

https://jqueryui.com/spinner/

Comment: I asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58674306/197591), and with the help of the answer, I was ultimately able to create a Blazor app with a JavaScript library (containing jQuery) using JavaScript interop. See my example [here](https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-examples/pull/139) (a GitHub PR).

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to create a wrapper for a JQuery or JS control:

1.- Enclose JS behavior in functions:

```
<script>
  var spinner = null;
  window.myWrapperKSUIfunctions = {

    initialize: function () {
        spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner();
        $( "button" ).button();
    },

    dissableclick: function () {
      if ( spinner.spinner( "option", "disabled" ) ) {
        spinner.spinner( "enable" );
      } else {
        spinner.spinner( "disable" );
      }
    },

    destroyclick: function () {
      if ( spinner.spinner( "instance" ) ) {
        spinner.spinner( "destroy" );
      } else {
        spinner.spinner();
      }
    },

    getvalueclick: function () {
      alert( spinner.spinner( "value" ) );
    },

    setvalueclick: function () {
      spinner.spinner( "value", 5 );
    },    
  };
</script>
```

*Don't forget to include other JS/JQuery libraries.*

2.- Initialize control from blazor:

```cs
@code {

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("myWrapperKSUIfunctions.initialize");
        }
    }
```

3.- Call JS function from blazor:

```html
  <button id="disable" 
          @onclick="@( ()=>JustCall("dissableclick") )" >
     Toggle disable/enable
  </button>
```

```cs
@code {

    ...
    protected async Task JustCall(string f)
    {
        wait JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>($"myWrapperKSUIfunctions.{f}"); 
    }
```

[Check it out at blazorfiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/1xw1xiam).

[image: demo]

Also, take a look to [MatBlazor](https://matblazor.com) controls.

Comment: Hi, I use Bootstrap 4 in my server-side Blazor app, but don`t include jQuery, because I see two comments in other posts [Here][1] and [Here][2]  and I got the impression that including jQuery in "_Host.cshtml" is not a good practice. Am I right or no? Thank you for your time :) .


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58427837/owl-carousel-not-working-with-asp-net-blazor?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment103197623_58427837
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54275133/8607675

Comment: @Alexander, Of course is better a clean project without JS neither JQuery. But, if you already have the jquery control and you need it in your code ASAP, what can you do? Rewrite from zero without javascript? Blazor has JSInterop to do it. Bootstrap need jquery for some features ( carrusel, popups, ... ) If you want to work without JS I suggest to you to move to an only css framework ( bulma, tailwind, ... )

Comment: thank you for your comment. The reason for my search is Bootstrap carousel and his swipe effect on a mobile phone. So maybe I will include the script for jQuery and all I need and continue to work, thank you again :).