# How to use bootstrap js in a razor page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to make a bootstrap carousel in my **Index.razor** because in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0) it says: *Don't place a  tag in a Razor component file (.razor) because the  tag can't be updated dynamically by Blazor.* But I need the **bootstrap js** to get my carousel working. How can I use the bootstrap js the cdn or save it in a file?

I also saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513221/how-to-use-bootstrap-carousel-in-blazor) but it do not help me because they use the `<script>` tag.

Comment: The documentation page you linked to in your question gives you several options, right below the warning you quoted. Did you try any of them?

Comment: The answer you linked to puts the script tag in the `index.html`. Therefore it does not break the rules outlined by the documentation because it's not a `.razor` file. You could also put the script into the `index.html`, or `_Layout.cshtml` or the `_Host.cshtml` depending on your build. You don't need the script to be inside your component for jsinterop.

Comment: The warnings are there for a reason: the two technologies aren't always compatible.  I personally never use bootstrap.js.  Blazor maintains a virtual DOM that it uses to write to the browser DOM when it re-renders.  Bootstrap.js makes changes that the Blazor Virtual DOM has no knowledge of,  and can therefore overwrite at the next render event!  [Polite]You can "want" as much as you like but you'll probably need to write some C# code to make it happen unless someone else has shared some relevant code. :-) Check out the Blazor libraries for Bootstrap.

Comment: @EricKing I tryed it but it did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shared post does not use `<script>` tag in .razor file. And I think you do not read the document entirely, pls read carefully for [the following doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#load-a-script-in-head-markup).

Assume that you use ASP.NET 6 Blazor Server app, you could follow the steps:

1.Add js file in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorApp1.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--startCarousel-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startCarousel(carouselId) {
            var myCarousel = document.getElementById(carouselId);
            var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel);
            carousel.cycle(); 
        }
    </script>
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

    <!--add js file-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>       

</body>
</html>
```

2.Modify your `Index.razor`:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<h3>Carousel</h3>
<!-- NOTE: the data-bs- attributes added as per the Bootstrap v5.1 instructions -->
<div id="@carouselName" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-wrap="true" data-bs-interval="2000" data-bs-pause="false">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/196/1920/1080" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1057/1920/1080" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1067/1920/1080" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>

@code {
    const string carouselName = "carouselExampleIndicators"; // NOTE: the ID of the carousel

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        object[] args = { carouselName };
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("startCarousel", args); // NOTE: call JavaScript function with the ID of the carousel
    }
}
```

**Update:**

After checking your repo, your `_Host.cshtml` is not correct, it should be:

```
@page "/"
@namespace RecommendationAlgorithmSample.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

Comment: thanks I tryed but now I get this [error](https://imgur.com/a/6UEbvzE)

Comment: Here is the [repo](https://github.com/Jonas-Pamminger/CSharp-recommendation-algorithm) if this helps you

Comment: Hi @HansPeter, updated. I got your point. My previous answer misunderstand you. I mean you can add js source and code in _Layout or _Host, give you a sample how to do in _Layout. I do not mean they are the same. Any way, I share the whole code.

Comment: sorry to bother you again but after such a long time I and you invested, I really want to get this working. No the side is loading but in the dev tool it says: [error](https://imgur.com/a/orujjzg) I think am missing something but I don't know what.

Comment: Hi @HansPeter, I suggest you can read my answer carefully, then you will see I add `startCarousel` js and `bootstrap` js in _Layout.cshtml. Or you can just copy my code.

Comment: You need to add `startCarousel.js` and `bootstrap.js` in `Layout.cshtml` it will work as said by Rena.

Comment: in `body` tag of your `Layout.cshtml` you can add like this `<script src="startCarousel.js"></script>`